# MongoDB prevent documents whose fields are equal

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a way to prevent Mongo from creating documents if two of their fields are equal?

For example, this should be accepted:

```
{ A: 'foo', B: 'bar' }
```

But this should be rejected:

```
{ A: 'foo', B: 'foo' }
```

It's simple enough to perform the check before making the call to Mongo, but the idea is to prevent mistakes if the collection is modified from the shell.

To be clear, I'm not trying to compare fields of one document against those of another document.  The values in the document just cannot conflict with other values in that same document.

Comment: Objects only support unique keys. So, I think you've got only manual way for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The easiest way of preventing mistakes by modifications from the shell is to implement a CRUD interface with validation. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, at its core it is pretty easy to do that, though it comes with a caveat I was not able to solve in a satisfying manner.

There is something called [schema validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/). We are going to use that, but instead of using an actual JsonSchema, we use a [query expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/#other-query-expressions) instead.

```
> db.runCommand({
  // We modify an existing collection named "validate"...
  collMod:"validate",
  // ...adding a validator...
  "validator":{
    // ...ensuring that documents are only considered valid if
    // the value of field A is not equal the value of field B
    $expr:{$ne:["$A","$B"]}}
  }
)
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

Let us put that to a test:

```
> db.validate.insert({"A":"foo","B":"bar"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.validate.insert({"A":"foo","B":"foo"})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
```

Yay, looks good so far, doesn't it? Except, there is a caveat:

```
> db.validate.insert({"A":"foo","B":"foo "})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

A simple whitespace can actually beat our little equality check. So obviously we need to expand our validator:

```
db.runCommand({collMod:"validate","validator":{$and:[
    // Both A and B must not have leading or trailing white space.
    {"A":{$regex:/^\w+$/}},
    {"B":{$regex:/^\w+$/}},
    // As before.
    {$expr:{$ne:["$A","$B"]}}
]}})
```

So, let us recheck:

```
db.validate.deleteMany({})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 2 }
> db.validate.insert({"A":"foo","B":"bar"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.validate.insert({"A":"foo","B":"bar "})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
> db.validate.insert({"A":"foo","B":"foo"})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
```

*Seems* to work. However, there is no way for the user to find out *why* the document validation failed. If you can live with that, you have your solution.
Personally, I'd rather implement a dedicated CLI tool doing the modifications, validating the input beforehand. Data modifications for production databases should not use the DBMS CLI.

Furthermore, there are use case related questions open: is "foo" equal "Foo" and "FOO"? And if that is the case, are A and B equal when A holds "fOo" and B holds "foO"? And so on and so forth.

Comment: Yeah there's already a custom interface to use so maybe that wasn't the best example, just felt like doing it like this is the most pleasing solution.  It's the only validation check I'd ever want so this is perfect, thanks!